# What is the best way to save video if I am building a site like youtube?

Tags: video, video-streaming

What is the best way to save video if I am building a site like YouTube ? I am using WebRTC for video recording, website is on JSF and server is tomcat. Currently I am saving video on file server and storing its path in database. I want to ask is there any better way to save videos like any special database ?

Comment: Please elaborate. What language will you be using? What's your service? What have you found so far?

Comment: I am using WebRTC for video recording, website is on JSF and server is tomcat. Currently I am saving video on file server and storing its path in database. I want to ask is there any other way to save videos like any special database ?

Comment: Ok, make sure to add that info to your question by using the `edit` button so someone doesn't mark your question unclear or off topic. That will prevent any answers from being posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot depends on the size and the location of your audience, but in very general terms separating the metadata (name, genre, actors etc information) from the actual video is a good approach.

The metadata typically is stored in a searchable storage like a traditional database, ElasticSearch, etc.

If your site is small and your users local to you and likely to connect over good speed connections then you might get away with simply hosting the videos themselves in a file systems on your server.

For any sort of large scale service, you will actually want to use a CDN and a streaming server.

The CDN essentially takes care of making sure that users in different locations get similar performance by storing copies of your video near the 'edge' of the network.

The streaming server is the 'origin' or the source for the CDN - it will generally support one or more streaming protocols (as different devices or browsers work best with different protocols) and you will most likely want it to support adaptive bit rate streaming, which essentially provides multiple copies of each video encoded in different bit rates, to cater for different network conditions.

It might be worth your while looking at some example streaming servers to get a feel for whether you need to go that way - some popular examples are:

- https://www.wowza.com
- http://www.videolan.org/vlc/streaming.html